# Oracle 11g JDBC prefetching keys

Tags: database, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, auto-increment

My app needs to know which row receives which key in the database.

I am using JDBC on read commited isolation level with batch updates. Therefore retrieving the keys with getGeneratedKeys isn't possible. My plan is to fetch a Range of ids from the database in a transaction safe way, e.g. two parallel transactions can't get the same keys.

Can I write some SQL-Query with the number of future rows as an argument to fetch a list of future keys in Oracle 11g?

What are my options here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use sequences for this purpose:

```
create sequence s;
```

to retrieve a id

```
select s.nextval from dual;
```

or to retrieve a range of ids :

```
select s.nextval from dual connect by level <= 10;
```

Comment: Thanks, could you maybe elaborate on transaction safty of this method? Is dual some magical pond for all auto incremented keys of all tables?

Comment: And how does dual know which table I needs keys for?

Comment: You may create as many sequences as you like. It's not uncommon to have one sequence per table. select table1_seq.nextval from dual; select table2_seq from dual; etc.

Comment: The table named DUAL is a small table in the data dictionary that Oracle Database and user-written programs can reference to guarantee a known result. This table has one column called DUMMY and one row containing the value X.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add:

There is no explicit relationship between sequences and tables.  A sequence is simply a mechanism for generating numerical sequences.  You can assume that a sequence will never produce a duplicate value, and that's about it.  Don't assume order, and *definitely* don't expect a gap-free sequence.  Sequences are done this way in Oracle, by design.  By following those rules, and making no other assumptions about a sequence's behavior, we get extremely scalable performance with sequences.  Note that as soon as you try to enforce an order or a gap-free sequence, your performance suffers severely.

In summary:
1.)  Sequences are dead simple, and really fast.
2.)  Other than "no dups", don't assume you can predict a sequence's behavior.
3.)  Sequences are independent objects, not tied to a table, and can be used to generate sequence values that will be used in the same table, or many different tables.

Hope that helps.